# Visual Studio 2015 Source Control System

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-2015, version-control

I just want to do some simple projects in Visual Studio 2015 (for a college project), and this popped into my eyes and I don't know what it means and what should I do. Until now I chose just to pass these options (cancel), but I would like to know in which cases (what kind of projects) these options of source control would represent a big benefit (or a must to use) and maybe you could tell me which one of these two options should I use.

[image]

Comment: Just be aware that that git description is rather ... off target? shortsighted? blinkered?  Everything after the word "that" in it is gimped somehow.

Comment: jthill, could you be more specific? why do you say this? I'm interested in your opinion

Comment: My first cut at a more accurate one would be "git is a distributed version control system that stores snapshots of project state. The usual criterion for what is stored is roughly ~enough to produce repeatable tests (and of course builds)~.  It provides tools for sharing them, and for working with them to create useful new ones.".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's asking you if you'd like to use one of a couple of well-known "version control" systems for storing your code and keeping track of the changes you make to it.

It's probably worth reading up on the general principles of version control (plenty to be found on Wikipedia, Microsoft websites etc) and seeing whether it's worth it for the projects you want to do.

Version control can be very powerful but it can also be very complex. It will allow you to see exactly what you changed in your project and code files, and when, each time you update them. You can compare the differences in a user friendly way, you can go back to older versions if you made a mistake, and you can even create multiple versions of your code and share the core features easily between them. If you need or want that then great, go for it. If you're just doing some small, short projects for personal use then maybe just making a backup of your files from time to time will be sufficient.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks! I'm doing just some small projects, so i'll just cancel this options and maybe use a backup for them.

Comment: I would argue that occasional backups is *not* sufficient for any size of project, and if you plan on working as a software developer, being able to work with a source control system is a benefit in my mind.

Comment: @crashmstr I'd agree in principle but it sounds like the OP is just starting out with programming in general, and as a hobby by the sounds of it...if so it's perhaps best to focus on that to start with and worry about version control once they decide they want to do it more seriously

Comment: you are right. I am just preparing myself for an exam in order to get into a computer science college...so I'm just beginning. But it's good to know from you, guys which are the next steps for me. For the moment, simple data structures, algorithms, etc .. you know better :) Thank you!

Comment: Agreed. Especially if you do regular backups that keep older versions of files around. Not quite as good as version control, but sufficient for a student's needs. I'll add that git isn't exactly Windows-friendly.

Comment: I highly recommend you to read into git asap. It's really worth and you will need it quite frequently. Plus, you're able to make revisions what you changed in case something doesn't works. Also you can work with different copies of your solution which is really powerful e.g. when working on different tasks.

Comment: Edward Falk, why do you say that Git is not really friendly with Windows?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't know what this means, then you can skip it for now. Then come back and learn version control later because it's a good thing to know about. And a must-know for a professional.

If you must choose one, choose git. It's quickly becoming the industry standard and it's completely free. Everybody uses [GitHub](http://github.com); I've never even heard of TeamFoundationVersionControlHub

Comment: Team Foundation Server (TFS) is Microsoft's version control system. It comes as part of Visual Studio online or it can be run standalone. (Visual Studio Online can also host git repositories). Git is probably an industry-standard in open-source circles but I'd be willing to bet, from my experience, that TFS is just as, if not more popular, in enterprises and Microsoft-only companies.